# Python Dash - How to take in the Input of Dropdown and Uploaded file for the Submit button

Tags: python, plotly-dash, dashboard

```
    html.H1(children='RailTec Dashboard'),
    #Uploading the files to the board. We want to make sure that two files can be uploaded, read, and grab the same categories to the direct coorelated category.
    #For choosing files between tabs
    html.Div(
    [
        html.H2("Upload"),
        dcc.Upload(
            id="upload-data",
            children=html.Div(
                ["Drag and drop or click to select a file to upload."]
            ),
            style={
                "width": "100%",
                "height": "60px",
                "lineHeight": "60px",
                "borderWidth": "1px",
                "borderStyle": "dashed",
                "borderRadius": "5px",
                "textAlign": "center",
                "margin": "10px",
            },
            multiple=True,
        ),
        html.H2("File List"),
        html.Ul(id="file-list"),
    ],
    style={"max-width": "500px"},
    ),
    #Drop Down Menu for the categories. 
    dcc.Dropdown(
        id = 'Categories',
        options=[
            {'label': 'Spikes', 'value': 'Spikes'},
            {'label': 'Fasteners', 'value': 'Fasteners'},
            {'label': 'Ballast Level', 'value': 'Ballast Level'},
            {'label': 'Spikes Med', 'value': 'Spikes'},
            {'label': 'Fasteners Med', 'value': 'Fasteners'},
            {'label': 'Ballast Level Med', 'value': 'Ballast Level'},
            {'label': 'Spikes Bad', 'value': 'Spikes'},
            {'label': 'Fasteners Bad', 'value': 'Fasteners'},
            {'label': 'Ballast Level Bad', 'value': 'Ballast Level'}
        ],
        placeholder="Select a category",
        value = 'Select'
    ),
    html.Div(id='dd-output-container'),

    html.Form([
    #Enter button Event to trigger app callback for dropdown and upload data to submit what to calculate.
    html.Div(id='target'),
    html.Button('Submit',id='submit', n_clicks=0),
    ], action = '/post', method='post')


    ])


#Uploading file definitions
def save_file(name, content):
    """Decode and store a file uploaded with Plotly Dash."""
    data = content.encode("utf8").split(b";base64,")[1]
    with open(os.path.join(UPLOAD_DIRECTORY, name), "wb") as fp:
        fp.write(base64.decodebytes(data))
def uploaded_files():
    """List the files in the upload directory."""
    files = []
    for filename in os.listdir(UPLOAD_DIRECTORY):
        path = os.path.join(UPLOAD_DIRECTORY, filename)
        if os.path.isfile(path):
            files.append(filename)
    return files
def file_download_link(filename):
    """Create a Plotly Dash 'A' element that downloads a file from the app."""
    location = "/download/{}".format(urlquote(filename))
    return html.A(filename, href=location)
    
@app.callback(
Output("file-list", "children"),
[Input("upload-data", "filename"), Input("upload-data", "contents")],)

def update_output(uploaded_filenames, uploaded_file_contents):
    """Save uploaded files and regenerate the file list."""

    if uploaded_filenames is not None and uploaded_file_contents is not None:
        for name, data in zip(uploaded_filenames, uploaded_file_contents):
            save_file(name, data)

    files = uploaded_files()
    if len(files) == 0:
        return [html.Li("No files yet!")]
    else:
        return [html.Li(file_download_link(filename)) for filename in files]

#Callback for dropdown menu
@app.callback(dash.dependencies.Output('dd-output-container', 'children'),[dash.dependencies.Input('Categories', 'value')])
def update_output(value):
    return 'You have selected "{}"'.format(value)


#Callback for submitting everything.
@app.callback(Output('target', 'children'), Input('submit', 'n_clicks'))
def callback(n_clicks):
    if ('n_clicks' != 0):
         return f'The result of the submission {n_clicks}'
```

I just need to be able to upload the file, choose a category(Drop down list), and then be able to submit by knowing the output which are the inputs of the upload and category(Dropdown list). Does anyone know how to do this?

I have the file list here where one can choose a category from the dropdown and press to submit which the calculations corresponding would then display a graph. My calculations are not displayed here as I need a way to use them for the app.callback to perform the calculations and display a graph from the function of my calculations which would be the output for my submit button.

[My Dashboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LyhUD.png)